# How can I stop having to disable and re-enable my network adaptor every time I go online?

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

I am running Win7Pro 64-bit SP1 with a TP-Link TD-W8968 modem connected to my laptop by Ethernet cable. Every time I power up the modem to go online, I find that my Intel I217-LM network adaptor isn't functioning and I need to disable it and then re-enable it. How can I stop having to do this?

Comment: Was this previously working in this manner, and stopped working? Or was the laptop or modem/wifi router recently set up?

Comment: In what order do you turn on/connect things? Power on laptop, power on modem, plug laptop into modem?
Typically the device providing [DHCP](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) must be on and ready to provide an IP address to your computer **before** the computer is connected to it.

Comment: @Smithy - It's been like this ever since I started using this modem, but wasn't like it with the previous modem. Usually I turn the modem on and then the laptop. The modem takes some time for all the lights to light up that are supposed to, and the laptop takes a while to boot too, so I don't know which counts as starting first.

Comment: @Smithy - I don't think that's the problem. I've now booted the laptop while the modem is off, and then disabled and re-enabled the network adaptor. Then when I turn the modem on and plug the Ethernet cable into the laptop, I connect to the internet without a problem.

Comment: When you say you're disabling and re-enabling your network adapter, is this in the device manager? Or under the "network connections" menu? While the connection is not working, what "IPv4 Address" do you have if you go through the following: Start button > Run > cmd > in the command propmt window enter "ipconfig" without quotes and hit enter. Before you connect to the modem, check this IPv4 address, then disable and re-enable the adapter, then check again. Then connect to the modem and check again.